# R shiny chorpleth map

Tags: r, csv, shiny, leaflet, choropleth

I am new in R. now I am creating shiny app.  R can read my dataset. with the comand myData <- read.csv("myData.csv"). however shinyServer file cannot read my data. and list no observation.
Could you guys help me what is the problem?
The Shinyapp provides interactive visulization for production of raw material in the world since 1900 to 2010 for every 10 years.
Also I keep getting this error: 
                   "ERROR: 'breaks' are not unique"

The Code is here:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  checkboxInput("type", "Please Select production type:",
                     c("Aluminium", "Gold", 
                       "Iron", "Silver", "Zinc")
  ),
  sliderInput("year","Choose a Year", 
              min = 1910,
              max = 2010,
              value= 2010),
  checkboxInput("Economy", "Please Select Economy Factor:", 
                     c("Income Inequallity", "labourers Real Wage", "GDP", "Inflation")),

  plotOutput("thisPlot"),
  leafletOutput("myMap")
)
)
```

shinyServer:

```
myData <- read.csv("myData.csv")
shinyServer<- function(input,output){

  output$myMap <- renderLeaflet({
    temp <- which(myData$type == input$type &
                    myData$year == input$year)
    myData <- myData[temp,]

    pal <- colorQuantile("YlGn", myData$production, n = 9)
    country_popup <- paste0("<strong>Estado: </strong>", myData$Country)

  leaflet(data = myData) %>% 
      setView(46.227638, 2.213749, zoom = 2) %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
     addPolygons( lng = ~myData$Long, lat = ~myData$Lat, 
                 fillColor = ~pal(myData$production), 
                     fillOpacity = 0.8, 
                     color = "#BDBDC3", 
                     weight = 1, 
                     popup = country_popup)


  })
}
```

the data is:

```
Names = c("id", 
"Country", "type", "year", "production", "GDP", "Income", "Inflation", 
"Laborer", "Lat", "Long"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10670L))
head(myData)
  id Country type year production GDP   Income Inflation   Laborer      Lat  
Long

 1  1  Guyana Gold 1910   0.000000   0 42.43048         0 154.45527 4.860416 
  -58.9301
```

it seems that it does read the data but it does not show it. and i have a problem with creating the choropleth map. which it does not work now in my shiny.

Comment: can you show us some of your data? i.e. by `dput(myData)` or `head(myData)` and can you insert a print statement before the colorQuantile() function call? `print(myData)`and tell us what the output in the console is?

Comment: Any feedback on this?

Comment: data.frame': 10670 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ id        : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Country   : Factor w/ 194 levels "Afghanistan",..: 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 ...
 $ type      : Factor w/ 5 levels "Aluminium","Gold",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ year      : int  1910 1920 1930 1940 1950 1960 1970 1980 1990 2000 ...
 $ production: num  0 7.42 2.09 7.91 6.05 ...
 $ GDP       : num  
 $ Income    : num  
 $ Inflation : num  
 $ Laborer   : num  
 $ Lat       : num  
 $ Long      : num

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, leaflet is finicky. I didn't have to make a lot of changes, you almost had it. One of the main problems was that your filter was usually yielding an empty dataframe which caused the markers not to show (of course).

This empty dataframe problem is also the cause for the `"ERROR: 'breaks' are not unique"` message since `colorQuantile` is getting a null input for its `domain` argument, which means it is doing an empty `quantile`, and all the breaks are zero and thus "not unique". This can also happen with highly skewed data. You should avoid calling it in that case - maybe fallback on `colorBin`, although detecting that can be a bit complicated.

The following changes were made.

- Added some fake data.
- Changed `addPolygons` to `addCircleMarkers` as `addPolygons` is for adding arbitray shapes that you specify.
- Changed your `checkBoxInput` to `checkBoxGroupInput` as you didn't want a checkbox, you wanted a group of them.
- Changed the filter clause to use `myData$type %in% input$type` instead of `myData$type == input$type` as you probably wanted membership.
- truncated the `input$year` value as it might not give back an integer, but your `year` values are definitely integers.
- Changed the border color to `"black"` so you could see it on the circle.
- Note that the `popup` does not come on hover, you have to click on the circle.
- removed the `myData` on the marker input as you have specified it on the `leaflet` call.
- commented out the `plotOutput` as I don't know what you want to plot.

Here is the code - this should get you started:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

# fake-up some data
n <- 10000
countrylist <- c("Guyana","Venezuela","Columbia")
typelist <- c("Aluminium", "Gold","Iron", "Silver", "Zinc")
types <- sample(typelist,n,replace=T)
cntrs <- sample(countrylist,n,replace=T)
lat <- 2.2 + 50*runif(n)
long <- -46 + 50*runif(n)
year <- sample(1910:2010,n,replace=T)
prd <- 100*runif(n)


myData <- data.frame(Country=cntrs,type=types,year=year,production=prd,Long=long,Lat=lat)

u <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  checkboxGroupInput("type", "Please Select production type:",
                c("Aluminium", "Gold","Iron", "Silver", "Zinc"),
                selected=c("Gold","Silver")
  ),
  sliderInput("year","Choose a Year", 
              min = 1910,
              max = 2010,
              value= 2010),
  checkboxGroupInput("Economy", "Please Select Economy Factor:", 
                c("Income Inequallity", "labourers Real Wage", "GDP", "Inflation")),
 # plotOutput("thisPlot"), 
  leafletOutput("myMap")
)
)

s <- function(input,output){

  output$myMap <- renderLeaflet({
    temp <- which(myData$type %in% input$type &
                    myData$year == trunc(input$year))
    print(nrow(myData))
    myData <- myData[temp,]
    print(nrow(myData))

    pal <- colorQuantile("YlGn", myData$production, n = 9)
    country_popup <- paste0("<strong>Estado: </strong>", myData$Country)

    leaflet(data = myData) %>% 
      setView(-46.227638, 2.213749, zoom = 2) %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      addCircleMarkers( lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat, 
                   fillColor = ~pal(myData$production), 
                   radius = 6, # pixels 
                   fillOpacity = 0.8, 
                   color = "black", 
                   weight = 1, 
                   popup = country_popup)
  })
}
shinyApp(u,s)
```

And this is the result:
[image]

Comment: Hi Mike Wise, Thanks a lot for your quick answer. This one works and is really good. only I need to add a specific value to each country and show it as a choropleth map. Do you have any idea how it can be happen?

Comment: Data is like: Country(country list), type(Gold, Silver, Zinc, Iron, Aluminum), Production Value(a number)

Comment: Would suggest you mark this one correct then, work on it a bit yourself, and when you get stuck post another question.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Sure.

Comment: You know how to mark it correct, right? You have to click on the check mark.